# How to programmatically change Z-Index of widget Stack in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-web, flutter-animation

As you can see in this Stack the yellow cube is at the bellow of a purple cube.

when I click, I want to change the index of the yellow cube to transform it from index 0 to 1 and the purple cube from index 1 to 0, vice versa.

[image: square]

I tried IndexedStack but it's only showing a single child from a list of children.

```
class _FlipIndex extends State<FlipIndex> {

  int currentIndex = 0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: GestureDetector(
        onTap: (){
          // Change Z-Index of widget
        },
        child: Stack(
          alignment: Alignment.center,
          children: [
            Transform.translate(
              offset: Offset(-30.0, 0.0),
              child: Container(
                width: 100,
                height: 100,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.yellow,
                  shape: BoxShape.rectangle,
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Transform.translate(
              offset: Offset(30.0, 0.0),
              child: Container(
                width: 100,
                height: 100,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.purple,
                  shape: BoxShape.rectangle,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: you have to change the order of widgets in `children:` array - there is no other way

Comment: as @pskink said you have to resort the `List` of `Widget`s but if you give proper `key` value to each `child` it would be done more efficiently

Comment: I'm looking for something similar to Z-Index in CSS, without changing the order manually, but programmatically, and, half of the purple cube should also appear below the yellow cube.

Comment: *"I'm looking for something similar to Z-Index in CSS,"* - there is no such thing

Comment: This is bad news, I appreciate your effort @pskink.

Comment: *"This is bad news,"* - whats wrong with ordering `children:` list?

Comment: I'm working on animation, every time I want to flip between indexes in Stack, at the same time keep half of each cube. Do you see the problem?

Comment: most likely you should use `CustomPaint` then

Comment: The solution that I found, is to create twice for each cube, then toggle between the state of the opacity.

Comment: @pskink you mean there's no such thing in flutter. There is in normal frameworks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
class _FlipIndex extends State<FlipIndex> {
  List<Widget> _stackChildren = [];
  int currentIndex = 0;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _stackChildren.add(_stackChild(Colors.yellow, 30));
    _stackChildren.add(_stackChild(Colors.green, -30));
  }

  //call this function for swapping items
  void _swapOrder() {
    Widget _first = _stackChildren[0];
    _stackChildren.removeAt(0);
    _stackChildren.add(_first);
    setState(() {});
  }

  Widget _stackChild(Color childColor, double xOffset) {
    return Transform.translate(
      key: UniqueKey(),
      offset: Offset(xOffset, 0.0),
      child: Container(
        width: 100,
        height: 100,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: childColor,
          shape: BoxShape.rectangle,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: GestureDetector(
        onTap: () {
          _swapOrder();
        },
        child: Stack(
          alignment: Alignment.center,
          children: _stackChildren,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Your solution is the same as IndexedStack, it's only showing a single child. Thanks Jim

Comment: NONON, you need to change the offset of 2 children too~, i didn't implement it, you need to change it and try

Comment: How change z-order without rebuild entire stack?

Answer (score 4):

Try this package https://pub.dev/packages/indexed

Example image:

[image: example image]

This package allows you to order items inside the stack using `index` like `z-index` in CSS.

Easily you can change the order of items by change the `index` property

This is an example of how it works

```
Indexer(
    children: [
        Indexed(
          index: 100,
          child: Positioned(
            //...
          )
        ),
        Indexed(
          index: 1000,
          child: Positioned(
            //...
          )
        ),
        Indexed(
          index: 3,
          child: Positioned(
            //...
          )
        ),
    ],
);
```

if you are using bloc of some complex widget you can extend or implement the `IndexedInterface` class and override `index` getter:

```
class IndexedDemo extends IndexedInterface {
    int index = 5;
}
```

or implements

```
class IndexedDemo extends AnimatedWidget implements IndexedInterface {
    int index = 1000;
    //...

    //...
}
```

then use it just like `Indexed` class widget:

```
Indexer(
    children: [
        IndexedDemo(
          index: 100,
          child: Positioned(
            //...
          )
        ),
        IndexedFoo(
          index: 1000,
          child: Positioned(
            //...
          )
        ),
    ],
);
```

Online [demo](https://dartpad.dev/?id=2bbadcf3554cf5d7222b62c639a18e5d&null_safety=true)
Video [demo](https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/22839194/131275765-9f1c037c-b4c5-4dfe-877f-14d5ee3f16e5.mp4)